# Trying to use an htaccess rule to fix %3F in query string issue on my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm building a Pebble Watchface config page on my website, and the automatically generated URL for that page from Cloud Pebble ends in %3F:

```
http://andr01dm.com/pebble/faciem/config.html?return_to=https%3A//cloudpebble.net/ide/emulator/config%3F
```

But this URL causes a 501 Method Not Implemented error on my site.  I've found that if I manually remove the %3F from the query string, it works as expected.

I was thinking of using an htaccess rule to change the URL to something like this:

```
http://andr01dm.com/pebble/faciem/config.html?return_to=cloud
```

I have written a rule which works in the website tool that I'm testing it in ( http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ ) but it doesn't work on my site.  Can you please have a look at my rule and let me know if it looks correct?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^return_to=https://cloudpebble\.net/ide/emulator/config\?$
RewriteRule config.html config.html?return_to=cloud [R=301,L]
```

My website is running Apache and ModX Revolution CMS.  Thank you.

Edit:  Here is the complete .htaccess from my site (minus the comments)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^andr01dm\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://^andr01dm.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^return_to=https://cloudpebble\.net/ide/emulator/config\?$
RewriteRule config.html config.html?return_to=cloud [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: did you write this (RewriteEngine On )

Comment: Yes, I have turned the rewrite engine on.  Here is the complete (minus comments) htaccess for my site: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^andr01dm\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://^andr01dm.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^return_to=https://cloudpebble\.net/ide/emulator/config\?$
RewriteRule config.html config.html?return_to=cloud [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

This aproach works for me:

```
# === remove extra question mark ===
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^(.*)%3F$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R,L]
```